# JMeter script to/from APIMATIC Format

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Convert JMeter script from/to Postman/Swagger is hard to impossible.

[APIMATIC](https://apimatic.io/transformer) Format can be converted from/to several formats as Swagger, Open API and Postman.

Is there a way to convert JMeter script to APIMATIC Format? Or maybe convert APIMATIC Format to JMeter script?

I didn't find such option in any site. Is it possible?

Comment: I'd say"easiest" (not really easy, but at least doable) from HTTP requests perspective would be converting JMeter script to HAR (for example with Fiddler), which is accepted as input format by apimatic. But all the logic / programmability is lost.

Comment: @Kiril S. Can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Kiril S. comment I found that Fiddler can save traffic as HAR file which can be converted to APIMATIC Format and also to JMX using [online blazemeter converter](http://converter.blazemeter.com/) by upload HAR file and click convert and then click on result file.